# Next-Auth getSession is returning null in my development environment

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using the following code in one of my pages:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context)
  return {
    props: { session }
  }
}
```

and the session is returning null. I get the following error:

```
[next-auth][error][client_fetch_error] [
  'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session',
  FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
```

if I try to navigate to *http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session* in my browser I get the session object normally. Also, my co-worker has the same code in his machine and it is working fine for him.

The only difference that I know between my environment and his is that I'm using windows and he is using mac. Not really sure if this can be causing the problem here.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: I had this same problem and it was because I put the next-auth environment variables in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete `.next` folder in your root directory and try again

Answer (score 1):

This problem is happening due to not specifying `e.preventDefault()` on login button.

The working code should look like this :-

```
async function login(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //Add this to your code.

    const getLoginStatus = await signIn("credentials", {
        redirect: false,
        username,
        password,
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by using straight ip address/domain name.

Try to use *127.0.0.1* instead of *localhost*, e.g.: *NEXTAUTH_URL=http://127.0.0.1:3000*